# facebook like button implementation in android app

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-like

I have gone through some sites and code to implement facebook like button in my android application. Where I realised that facebook not providing sdk for like implementation.

I want facebook like implementation without redirecting anywhere from my application and not to use webview.

And I found one library [shamanland library](http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/06/facebook-like-button-for-android.html) to integrate facebook like button.But I don't know how to import that library into my eclipse coz it depends on gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the library you mentioned in Maven central and it has a [.aar file](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/shamanland/facebook-like-button/0.1.8/facebook-like-button-0.1.8.aar).

I think your only option would be to download the .aar file and extract it (like a zip file), then manually add the sources and resources to your project.

Though I myself haven't done this. So, no guarantees.